# Up to date ClamAV on Debian Wheezy (ClamAV installation is OUTDATED log message)

Tags: debian-wheezy, clamav

I've installed ClamAV on Debian Wheezy from the offical repositories, using apt. System is up to date and I don't get any updates via `apt-get upgrade`, but still I get this message in the logs:

```
Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
```

My version is:

```
$ clamscan -V
ClamAV 0.98.1/19186/Sun Jul 13 00:34:56 2014
```

On the official page:

> Latest ClamAV® stable release is: 0.98.4

Looks like the official stable repos for Wheezy are not up to date. The only information I've found is [official info](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/packages/packages-linux/) about Debian [Volatile project](https://www.debian.org/volatile/), which is now closed since Squeeze.

Are there any alternative repositories?
How can I keep ClamAV always up to date and be sure the system is stable?

Edit:

My `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free



$ dpkg -l 'clamav*'


||/ Name                                     Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-========================================-=========================-=========================-======================================================================================
ii  clamav                                   0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2      amd64                     anti-virus utility for Unix - command-line interface
ii  clamav-base                              0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2      all                       anti-virus utility for Unix - base package
ii  clamav-daemon                            0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2      amd64                     anti-virus utility for Unix - scanner daemon
un  clamav-data                              <none>                                              (no description available)
ii  clamav-docs                              0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2      all                       anti-virus utility for Unix - documentation
ii  clamav-freshclam                         0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2      amd64                     anti-virus utility for Unix - virus database update utility
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I down some digging read [The Perfect Server - Debian Wheezy (Apache2, BIND, Dovecot, ISPConfig 3) - Page 3](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-wheezy-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p3) This sorted my "Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!"

First make sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains the wheezy-updates repository (this makes sure you always get the newest updates for the ClamAV virus scanner - this project publishes releases very often, and sometimes old versions stop working), and that the contrib and non-free repositories are enabled (some packages such as `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` are not in the main repository).

Add these lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run command `apt-get update` then `apt-get dist-upgrade` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the basic `wheezy` repository is enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

It's a bit odd; newest clamav on Wheezy is not on `wheezy-updates` repository, but `wheezy` repository instead:

```
wheezy-update: 0.98.1+dfsg-1+deb7u4
wheezy       : 0.98.4+dfsg-0+deb7u2
```

If you haven't enabled any apt pinning (need not worry about it if you don't know those settings, otherwise the pinning must be undone), `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` should be fetching newest version after `apt-get update`.

Comment: Looks like it's enabled. I've updated the question with the sources.

Comment: @sfisioza, maybe you want to post output of `dpkg -l 'clamav*'` on your post? There's some slight possibility that old deb package version might contain epoch number, which blocks installation of any newer version.

Comment: Added the list of packages.

Comment: @Sfisioza You already have newest package. `clamscan` reporting different version highly suggests another custom installed ClamAV. Can you try running this command: `type clamscan` and check where this `clamscan` comes from?

Comment: `clamscan is /usr/bin/clamscan`. The updates came with the latest wheezy upgrades, do I don't get the warnings for now.

Comment: Then you can try `clamscan -V` now.

Comment: Yes, currently is up to date.