# Is there a way to keep ClamAV updated on Debian 8?

Tags: debian, clamav, debian-jessie

Since upgrading to Debian 8 my syslog is full of

```
...freshclam[17851]: WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
...freshclam[17851]: WARNING: Local version: 0.98.7 Recommended version: 0.99
...freshclam[17851]: DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
```

While trying not to panic, as instructed, I followed the link. Which goes to a 404! **Panic!** [joke. EDIT: this link is now working.]

Virus scanners need to be updated regularly, and these updates do not make it into Debian stable frequently. In days gone by we had a "volatile" repo for virus checkers etc. in Debian, then we had [workarounds for Wheezy](https://serverfault.com/questions/612201/up-to-date-clamav-on-debian-wheezy-clamav-installation-is-outdated-log-message). What about Debian 8, Jessie?

Ideally I'd like to stick with apt for package management, especially as I have unattended upgrades running for security updates.

Comment: Shouldn't updates to something like ClamAV *automatically* count as security updates, and be pushed out frequently by the package maintainers? If not, why not?

Comment: Wasn't 0.99 released just a few days ago?  You might try submitting a bug report, but it does seem from the devel list that they are aware that 0.99 is released and they are working on updating.  http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-clamav-devel/

Comment: The link doesn't returns 404 right now. Instead it gives 302 and redirects to  http://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure... there is difference between virus definitions version and program version. Program version is always a bit behind on debian, but if you have virus updates working fine, there is no reason to panic. In fact, there's not much reason to do anything IMHO. :)

Answer (score -1):

Seriously there is no need to panic. Look at your local version (0.98.7) and the latest version(0.99).

Anyway all you need to do is `apt-get upgrade clamav` whenever you are ready.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for taking the time to answer. However, `apt upgrade` won't cut it; ClamAV changes faster than Debian stable's repos do. The [latest stable version](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/clamav) is installed. The question is asking how/whether there is an always-up-to-date debian repo for ClamAV.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the debian wiki about updates for stable releases](https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates) you need to have

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`; then `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` will bring you the latest version of *clamd*.

Comment: I don't see that url listed in your link.  Am I missing something?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/StableUpdates <- this one?